Iterating over a nested array of objects to create a new object
I have a nested array of objects that looks something like this:
[
 [
  {
   name: 'name',
   prettyFormat: 'joe bloggs'
   uselessInfo: 'drjfghsdr'
  },
  {
   name: 'email',
   answer: 'joe.bloggs@gmail.com',
   uselessInfo: 'liodrgjiwe'
  }
 ]
 [
  {
   name: 'name',
   prettyFormat: 'mark obrien',
   uselessInfo: 'drjfghsdr'
  },
  {
   name: 'email',
   answer: 'mark obrien@gmail.com',
   uselessInfo: 'liodrgjiwe'
  }
 ]
]

I need to transform this array into something more sensible, actually a JSON object, with the following format:
{
  "LIST": [
    {
      "name": "joe bloggs",
      "email": "joe.bloggs@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "name": "mark o'brien",
      "email": "mark obrien@gmail.com",

    },
  ]
}

This is my solution:
  let outputBuilder = []

  staffSubmissionsArray.forEach(subArray => {
    let personObj = {}
    subArray.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.name == 'name') {
        personObj['name'] = obj.prettyFormat
      } if (obj.name == 'email') {
        personObj['email'] = obj.answer
      } 
      outputBuilder.push(personObj)
    })
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ "LIST" : outputBuilder })

This gets everything into the right format, however, each person is getting duplicated, presumably each time I iterate over each object, but I don't know how to fix this. Do I need to approach this in a different way?

outputBuilder.push(personObj) is happening inside the inner loop, move it out (down 1 line)

In your data example, you are missing a comma after 'joe bloggs' and between the two outer array items (] [).

What if your nested array has more than 2 objects, some with name properties that are neither "email", nor "name"? Should the output ignore those objects?

there are several other name properties aside from 'email' and 'name'.. some are needed and some are not. I had filtered those out in an earlier section of code.

So we can be sure that there are never more than two objects in the subarrays, and that they have just email and name, or how does this work?

There are more than two objects in the arrays, i just stuck to 'name' and 'email' for brevity in this case. The suggestion by @James has fixed the problem

You can also use only the map method map(), together with the optional chaining .? and the nullish coalescing ?? operators:


const data = [
  [
    {
      name: 'name',
      prettyFormat: 'joe bloggs',
      uselessInfo: 'drjfghsdr'
    },
    {
      name: 'email',
      answer: 'joe.bloggs@gmail.com',
      uselessInfo: 'liodrgjiwe'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: 'name',
      prettyFormat: 'mark obrien',
      uselessInfo: 'drjfghsdr'
    },
    {
      name: 'email',
      answer: 'mark obrien@gmail.com',
      uselessInfo: 'liodrgjiwe'
    }
  ]
];

const transformedData = {"LIST": data.map(([obj1, obj2]) => ({
  name: obj1?.prettyFormat ?? obj2?.prettyFormat ?? "Name not found!",
  email: obj2?.answer ?? obj1?.answer ?? "Email not found!"
}))};

console.log(JSON.stringify(transformedData, null, 2));




Another alternative is;


      const data = [
        [
          {
            name: 'name',
            prettyFormat: 'joe bloggs',
            uselessInfo: 'drjfghsdr'
          },
          {
            name: 'email',
            answer: 'joe.bloggs@gmail.com',
            uselessInfo: 'liodrgjiwe'
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            name: 'name',
            prettyFormat: 'mark obrien',
            uselessInfo: 'drjfghsdr'
          },
          {
            name: 'email',
            answer: 'mark obrien@gmail.com',
            uselessInfo: 'liodrgjiwe'
          }
        ]
      ];

      let outputBuilder = [];

      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          outputBuilder.push(
            {
              "name":  data[i][0].prettyFormat, 
              "email": data[i][1].answer
            }
         )
       }

      console.log(JSON.stringify({ "LIST" : outputBuilder },null,2))



